# How to load image object downloaded from aws s3 using signedURL in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, vue.js, vuejs2, base64

```
<div v-for="(data, key) in imgURL" :key="key">
 <img :src= "getLink(data)" />
</div>
```

Where imgURL contains file name and it is collections of file names.

```
  methods: {
     async getLink(url){
      let response = await PostsService.downloadURL({
        imgURL : url
      })
      //return response.data
      let imgdata = await axios.get(response.data)
      console.log(imgdata.data)
      return imgdata.data
     }
  }
```

In console it prints base64 image which is

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwAAAAHkCAIAAAAGqd9kAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBnbm9tZS1zY3JlZW5zaG907wO/PgAAIABJREFUeJ.....

But image is not loading.

I tried linking direct url which is generated from server but no use because I am storing part of the file name and using it to generate complete URL. The generated signedURL is, in above code is "response.data".

I am uploading images using fileReader and axios with signedURL.

I want to know where the problem is?

Comment: Do you really need base64 encoded images data or you just want to show images?

Comment: When I upload an image to s3 using fileReader, it is uploading as base64 image. So I need to download and display it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use base64 encoded data to display image, it is slow. I would say, simply use signed url. I was doing the same as you are doing but later found that no need to download an image data instead simply use signed url as image source. Also generating signed url is synchrounous which makes it easy to handle code.

So instead of this

```
<div v-for="(data, key) in imgURL" :key="key">
  <img :src= "getLink(data)" />
</div>
```

Do this

```
<div v-for="(data, key) in imgURL" :key="key">
  <img :src="data" />  // I am not Vue guy, so use `data` value here
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this but the problem here is data value is part of file name so using that I will generate complete signedURL and returning that value but no use. methods: {
     async getLink(url){
      let response = await PostsService.downloadURL({
        imgURL : url
      })
      return response.data
     }
  }

Comment: can you paste a sample signed url with fake values in your question?

Comment: So your image is accessable but not in correct format. Can you confirm by downloading image from aws s3 console that images are being uploaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For Load presigned image url, In Vue3 and Vuetify3, You have use below instructions:

simply, you have to use lazy-src , eager and src props like example:

```
 <VAvatar rounded size="120">
            <VImg
              cover
              :src="release.artwork_image"
              :lazy-src="release.artwork_image"
              alt="loading"
              eager
            />
          </VAvatar>
```

Or For add Custom loader you can use another 2 approach like below:

```
<VAvatar rounded size="120">
           <img
              class="v-img__img v-img__img--cover"
              width="100"
              height="100"
              :src="release.artwork_image"
              @load="onImageLoad"
            />
            <VProgressCircular
              v-if="imgloader"
              :size="30"
              width="3"
              color="primary"
              indeterminate
            /> 
          </VAvatar>
```

and Your @load event will be,

```
<script setup> 
  const imgloader = ref(true);
  const onImageLoad = () => {
   imgloader.value = false;
 };
```

Thank You, hope it will helps you a lot :) happy coding